# ajax prefilter checking is not doing its work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the code which i am running to check that my session is check before any ajax call is made, i have added a `successCheck` in the code to check if its not going recursive, but it shows in network panel, it works but not in the console.

any idea what i am doing wrong here

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  console.log(options);
  // Check if the request is an AJAX call
  if (options.type.toLowerCase() !== "post" && options.type.toLowerCase() !== "get") {
      return;
  }

  // Check if the sessionCheck option is present
  if (options.sessionCheck === false) {
    console.log('hello');
    return;
  }

  // Run the session expiration check before each AJAX call
  checkSessionBeforeAjax(jqXHR);
});

function checkSessionBeforeAjax(jqXHR) {
  // Make an AJAX call to check if the session has expired
  $.ajax({
      url: "checkSession.cfm",
      type: "POST",
      sessionCheck: false,
      success: function(response) {
        var _resp = $.parseJSON(response);
        console.log(_resp);
        var status = _resp[1];
        alert(status);
          if (status === "expired") {
              // Display a popup message to the user with a high z-index
              customSwal('success',_resp[1],
                () => { 
                  window.location.href = 'logout.cfm';
                }
            );
          }
      }
  });
}
```

there are many ajax calls in my code, which runs one after one, so this check is for those and it runs before each ajax request, i was also wondering if this could just check the first call i am making and show a sweetAlert and halt all others if the alert is shown and user navigates to logout screen. on click ok OK button.

Comment: "it works but not in the console" - what does that mean?

Comment: `checkSessionBeforeAjax()` is asynchronous. So you won't wait for it to finish before the prefilter function returns.

Comment: And it won't help to `await` it, either, because jQuery doesn't await the `ajaxPrefilter` callback.

Comment: @barmar you are correct, it does not seems to be waiting for it,  it just executes numerous times and then it displays a message but it still displays the message,  how can i make it check that all ajax calls even if i have 10 or 20 will run after the ajaxprefilter or ajaxsend sends a success which says its active and if its expired, just display a  sweetalert message, how can i modify it

Comment: I don't think you can do this with any of the built-in AJAX functions. I suggest you write a wrapper function of your own that performs the session check, then executes the actual AJAX call in its `success:` function if the session is still alive.

Comment: and can you explain it more, it would be very helpful like what kind of wrapper you are asking, you mean before the server file is called, it will cehck for session file and see if its valid, if will return true and show a logout popup, but will that halt all other ajax calls which run run one after the other ?